# Linux/Debian: How to find out if a package has been installed via package manager (apt) or manually using dpkg?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg

I'm using a Debian cloud instance and am wondering how to list all of the packages that have been installed manually, e.g. by using `dpkg` on a `.deb` file, as opposed to via the package manager `apt`.

I tried `apt list --installed | grep <pkg_name>` but there's no hint as to how the items shown in result were installed.

Is there any command / procedure by which I could find this out?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to list packages installed by dpkg, you obviously would need to use dpkg for listing them, not apt. `dpkg -l` will do that

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, it is easy. If it installed, it is installed by `dpkg`. Really the other programs are better user interfaces which call `dpkg` for the installing work (and usually with better dependency check, and automatic downloading of packages). In any case you see in `/var/log/dpkg.log` all installation/deinstallation work.

In logs you have also what `aptitude` did, and what `apt` did. Probably other system program log transaction in  `/var/log`.